# SQL query to get all records in a certain status within a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a fairly big table (10,000+ records) that looks more or less like this:

```
| id | name  | contract_no | status |
|----|-------|-------------|--------|
| 1  | name1 | 1022        | A      |
| 2  | name2 | 1856        | B      |
| 3  | name3 | 1322        | C      |
| 4  | name4 | 1322        | C      |
| 5  | name5 | 1322        | D      |
```

contract_no is a foreign key which of course can appear in several records and each record will have a status of either A, B, C, D or E.

What I want is to get a list of all the contract numbers, where ALL the records referencing that contract are in status C, D, E, or a mix of those, but if any of the records are in status A or B, omit that contract number.

Is it possible to do this using a SQL query? Or should I better export the data and try to run this analysis using another language like Python or R?

Comment: which RDBMS?........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post aggregate filtering should do the trick

```
SELECT contract_no FROM t
GROUP BY contract_no
HAVING SUM(status='A')=0
AND SUM(status='B')=0
```

Comment: what about `HAVING SUM(status='A')+SUM(status='B')=0` ?

Comment: Could also be `HAVING SUM(status IN ('A', 'B')) = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` with `having` to get such contract numbers.

```
select contract_number
from yourtable 
group by contract_number
having count(distinct case when status in ('C','D','E') then status end) >= 1
and count(case when status = 'A' then 1 end) = 0
and count(case when status = 'B' then 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that elegant as the other two answers, but more expressive:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contract_no
FROM the_table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM the_table t2
    WHERE t2.contract_no = t1.contract_no
    AND t2.status IN ('A', 'B')
)
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT contract_no
FROM the_table
WHERE contract_no NOT IN (
    SELECT contract_no
    FROM the_table
    AND status IN ('A', 'B')
)
```